# At what rate does the sun generate in PvZ2?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

This Q&A contained 2 contradictory statements: [Efficiency of Single vs Double Sunflowers at the start of the level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133848/efficiency-of-single-vs-double-sunflowers-at-the-start-of-the-level)

1. Sun generated from the "sky" is generated faster than sunflowers-produced sun
2. Opposite.

**So, between a single sunflower, a double sunflower, and "sky", what's the exact rate/speed of sun generation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this.

At the start of a game, I planted one sunflower.

One sun dropped before the sunflower produced its first sun.

By the time the first zombie appeared, 5 suns total had dropped, and the single sunflower had only produced one sun.

The rate of both sun drops and sunflower production appears fixed.  A single sunflower appears to produce sun approximately every 20 seconds or so (I was not using a stopwatch, so my count may have been slightly fast, but I counted 21, 22, 21, and 21  approximate second intervals for a single sunflower; my counts for a double sunflower were similar, to +/- 1 approximate second).

Sun drops, on the other hand, appear to drop regularly approximately every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The sun drops 5 seconds after the game starts, it then regularly drop every 9 seconds